# MySQL query working for hours and hours and never finishing

Tags: mysql, performance, time, timeout

I have been slowly building up a query, and when I got to this point, I did not change the number of rows to return or the number of "pitchers" to return data for; just how much data for each one, and my query has been spinning for 12 hours with no resolution in sight. Is there anything I could have done wrong in writing my query to make it be taking so long without any results? If you take away the "rsgames2" and "teamdata" tables, this same query only took about 25 minutes.

```
SELECT  AVG(outertable.dis) AS disaverage, outertable.yr,
        outertable.pitcher AS pitcher,
        outertable.pitch_type AS pitch_type, outertable.war, outertable.gs,
        outertable.temp, rsgames2.ATTEND_PARK_CT, rsgames2.DAYNIGHT_PARK_CD,
        rsgames2.WIND_SPEED_PARK_CT, teamdata.LNPop, teamdata.PPMult,
        teamdata.FCI
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  distinct sqrt(((abs((power(pitches.px- myavgtable.apx, 2)) +
                     power(pitches.pz-myavgtable.apz,2))))) AS dis, myavgtable.yr,
                myavgtable.pitcher, myavgtable.pitch_type, myavgtable.war,
                myavgtable.gs, myavgtable.temp, myavgtable.game_id, myavgtable.HOME
            FROM  
              ( SELECT  distinct atbats.pitcher AS pitcher, YEAR(games2.DATE) AS yr,
                        pitches.pitch_type AS pitch_type, pitches.pitch_type AS pt,
                        AVG(pitches.px) AS apx,
                        AVG(pitches.pz) AS apz,
                        pitcherwar.WAR as war,
                        pitcherwar.GS as gs,
                        games2.temp as temp,
                        games2.game_id AS game_id, games2.HOME as HOME
                    from  atbats
                    join pitches on pitches.ab_id = atbats.ab_id
                    join pitcherwar on atbats.pitcher = pitcherwar.eliasid
                    join games2 on atbats.game_id = games2.game_id
                    where  atbats.pitcher = games2.home_starting_pitcher
                      AND  atbats.pitcher = pitcherwar.eliasid
                      AND  pitches.pitch_type != 'IN'
                      AND  pitches.pitch_type != 'PO'
                      AND  pitches.pitch_type != 'UN'
                      AND  YEAR(games2.DATE)>=2008
                    group by  atbats.pitcher, pitches.pitch_type, yr
              ) AS myavgtable
            JOIN atbats  ON atbats.pitcher=myavgtable.pitcher
            JOIN pitches  ON atbats.ab_id=pitches.ab_id
            JOIN games2 on atbats.game_id=games2.game_id 
      ) AS outertable
    JOIN rsgames2 on outertable.game_id = rsgames2.game_id
    JOIN teamdata on outertable.HOME = teamdata.Team
      and  outertable.yr = teamdata.Year
    WHERE  outertable.dis IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY  outertable.pitcher, outertable.pitch_type, outertable.yr;
```

Comment: you should do EXPLAIN on the query, also i m surprised why didnt the query got timed out.

Comment: What is the number of records rows you have in each table

Comment: Do you have indexes for this query

Comment: Could you post the explain result for this query

Comment: I am not that learned in SQL... how do I find my "explain" results?

Comment: Also, as for how many rows, one table has ~6m, one table has around ~1.2m, one has about ~40k and the rest have a few hundred each

Comment: Using the mysql commandline tool, perform `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Change to `AND  pitches.pitch_type NOT IN ('IN', 'PO', 'UN')`

Comment: Change to `AND games2.DATE >= '2008-01-01'`; what you have hides the date in a function, making it unusable for indexing.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for each table.

Comment: You are missing a comma before `pitcherwar.GS`?

Comment: Have you successfully run this query for a shorter time period?  i.e. instead of `>='2008-01-01' `use a more current date `>='2016-01-01'`, the idea here is to run on smaller data set. Additionally, try to run queries which construct `myavgtable` and `outertable` and ensure they are returning results in desirable time frame. This will help you narrow down where is issue lies.

Comment: All, thank you for your help. This ended up just taking 18 hrs to finish and work successfully. It did not time out because this is a local server on my home PC for a personal project I am working on.